# Environment variable in php script not working from nohup

Tags: php, debian, nohup

I have php script which uses some environment variables using getenv from /etc/environment. It works fine when I run it from terminal using php command. But environment variables are not getting when running same script from nohup on terminal.

PHP is 5.3 using Debian 6.

Comment: Can you show you terminal command , and what is `nohup` ?

Comment: @ShivanRaptor nohup is a linux command to run scripts in the a background instead of terminal.

Answer (score 0):

I have no problem:

```
nohup php -r 'var_export(getenv("PATH"));'
```

Same result with

```
php -r 'var_export(getenv("PATH"));'
```

Maybe you are talking with user env var ?

```
MY_VAR=42;
nohup php -r 'var_export(getenv("MY_VAR"));'
# The output will return false.
# You need to use export


export MY_VAR=42;
nohup php -r 'var_export(getenv("MY_VAR"));'
```

Comment: I have environment variable named DATABASE_URL in /etc/envirment file. And in my php code I am accessing it like $db = getenv('DATABASE_URL'). It does work when I run script like php script.php but not when I run it like nohup php script.php&

Comment: And using you second example with export, I am still getting false. Is there anything settings I need to change in php or debian config?

Comment: On Ubuntu and Debian I get the correct result... event with export and /etc/environment